# SQL Display info with Max(count(*))

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group

This query currently shows max(hella) so far

```
SELECT max(hella)
FROM (
SELECT G.firstname, G.lastname, count(*) as hella
FROM guest G, Timeslot TS, shows H
where G.timeslotnum = TS.timeslotnum
AND TS.shownumber = H.shownumber
AND H.showname = 'Fitness'
Group by g.firstname, G.lastname
ORDER by hella
)
As blabla
```

I want to show firstname and lastname of max(hella) entry

Comment: Do you want all ties for the maximum, or just one (arbitrarily)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much like what @maniek or @zfus already posted: returns a single row, arbitrary pick if there are ties.
But with proper JOIN syntax and shorter with some syntax candy:

```
SELECT g.firstname, g.lastname, count(*) AS hella
FROM   guest    g
JOIN   timeslot t USING (timeslotnum)
JOIN   shows    s USING (shownumber)
WHERE  s.showname = 'Fitness'
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 3 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94095/5) (reusing @sgeddes' fiddle).

Comment: Thanks! If im understanding this correctly, we order in descending order then take the first entry which would logically be the max, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it @user3241846. The danger with some of the answers using `limit 1` or `fetch first 1 rows only` is that if John Smith and Max Taylor both had a count of 45 (which was the max count), only one will show up.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT G.firstname, G.lastname, count(*) as hella
FROM guest G, Timeslot TS, shows H
where G.timeslotnum = TS.timeslotnum
AND TS.shownumber = H.shownumber
AND H.showname = 'Fitness'
Group by g.firstname, G.lastname
ORDER by hella desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

While SoulTrain and sgeddes have an answer from one angle, if your desire is to show only one record with the max count, you could simply write something like this:

```
SELECT G.firstname, G.lastname, count(*) as hella
FROM 
    guest G,
    Timeslot TS, 
    shows H
where 
    G.timeslotnum = TS.timeslotnum
    AND TS.shownumber = H.shownumber
    AND H.showname = 'Fitness'
Group by 
    g.firstname, 
    G.lastname
ORDER by 
    hella desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

[Example in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f94a/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
WITH CTE as
(
SELECT G.firstname, G.lastname, count(*)  as hella
FROM guest G, Timeslot TS, shows H
where G.timeslotnum = TS.timeslotnum
AND TS.shownumber = H.shownumber
AND H.showname = 'Fitness'
Group by g.firstname, G.lastname
)
SELECT firstname, lastname, hella
FROM CTE A
WHERE hella= (SELECT MAX(HELLA) FROM CTE B
WHERE A.firstname=B.firstname
and A.lastname=B.lastname)
As blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but assuming you're looking for the first and last name of the person with the most record count, something like this should work:

```
with cte as (
  select g.firstname, g.lastname, count(*) cnt
  from guest g
      join timeslot ts on g.timeslotnum = ts.timeslotnum
      join shows s on ts.shownumber = s.shownumber and s.showname = 'Fitness'
  group by g.firstname, g.lastname
)
select firstname, lastname
from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94095/1)